# Windows Forms - Won't draw a ball

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, draw

So I'm playing around with Windows forms in Visual Studio and I'm trying to create a simple program that just draws a ball using the `Graphics` class.

Here is the code for the ball class:

```
public class Ball
{
    public Point centre { get; set; }
    public int state { get; set; }
    public static int radius = 40;

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        Brush brush;
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        if(state==0)
        {
           brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        }
        if(state==1)
        {
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        }
        if(state==2)
        {
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        }
        g.FillEllipse(brush, centre.X - radius, centre.Y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    }

    public void Move(Point centre)
    {
        this.centre = centre;
    }
}
```

And here is the class for the main program:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Ball ball { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ball = new Ball();
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;
        ball.centre = new Point(250, 250);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        ball.state = 1;
        ball.Draw(g);
    }
}
```

However whenever I launch the program it runs successfully with no errors but doesn't draw anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few modifications to the `Ball` class to manage a `List<Color>`, so more colors can be added at run-time, some default properties and `IDisposable` support.

Also, the rendering quality is enhanced, using [Graphics.SmoothingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), set to `AntiAlias` and [Graphics.CompositingQuality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.compositingquality(v=vs.110).aspx), set to `HighQuality`.

```
public class Ball : IDisposable
{
    private SolidBrush brush = null;
    private int PrivateState = 0;

    public Ball()
        : this(new Point(40, 40)) { }

    public Ball(Point InitialPosition)
    {
        this.FillColorList();
        this.Centre = InitialPosition;
        this.Radius = 40;
        this.brush = new SolidBrush(this.Colors[this.PrivateState]);
    }

    public Point Centre { get; set; }
    public int State {
        get { return this.PrivateState; }
        set { this.PrivateState = (value < this.Colors.Count) ? value : 0; }
    }
    public int Radius { get; set; }
    public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }

    private void FillColorList()
    {
        this.Colors = new List<Color>() { Color.White, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Red };
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        this.brush.Color = this.Colors[this.PrivateState];
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.FillEllipse(brush, Centre.X - Radius, Centre.Y - Radius, 2 * Radius, 2 * Radius);
    }

    public void Move(Point NewCentre) => this.Centre = NewCentre;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.brush != null)
            this.brush.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your `Ball` object is still a Property value, but you might want to use a List instead, so you can manage more object at the same time.

`Form` settings:
(Note that the `Paint()` and `FormClosing()` events are registered in the `Form` constructor, so make sure they're not registered elsewhere, unless they're used for some other reasons).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ball = new Ball(new Point(250, 250));
    ball.State = 1;  // <- Will draw a green ball
    this.Paint += (s, e) => { ball.Draw(e.Graphics); };
    this.FormClosing += (s, e) => { ball.Dispose(); };
}

public Ball ball { get; set; }
```

When you want to move the `Ball` object, set the new position and call `this.Invalidate()` to raise the `Form` `Paint()` event:

```
ball.Colors.Add(Color.Orange);
ball.State = this.ball.Colors.Count - 1;  // <- Will draw an orange ball
ball.Radius = [new Radius];
ball.Move(new Point([X], [Y]));
this.Invalidate();
```